# Queries for cleansing string data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with name and address columns. I need to create two new columns that will hold modified values from these two columns, with special characters cleansed.

Please help with the queries.

Comment: I'd consider REPLACE.

Comment: Please provide sample strings and how they sould look after "cleansing".

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

you have 2 options:

- use triggers:

> CREATE TRIGGER MyTableFillCollumns ON MyTable
>   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
>   AS
>      UPDATE MyTable 
>        SET ColumnWithoudDiacritics) = Replace(Column, 'Á', 'A')
>      FROM MyTable m
>              JOIN inserted AS i
>              ON m.Id = i.Id
>   RETURN
>   END;

- use computed columns (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2481/getting-creative-with-computed-columns-in-sql-server/)

new column will have a formula like this

> (replace(CONVERT(nvarchar,[Column],0),'Á','A'))

Comment: Please elaborate some details of your suggested solution, including code examples.